# How to save a record in mongoDB with array object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Save the following object as a record in mongodb, using MongooseJS module.

```
const object = {
    num: 'IVN21034',
    date: '2019/09/02',
    lines: [{
            item_id: 1,
            qty: 1,
            price: 10
        }, {
            item_id: 2,
            qty: 1,
            price: 10
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const mongoose = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        db = "dburl";
        dbo = mongoose.connect(db),
        response = await dbo.collection("<tablename>").insertOne(<object to be inserted>);
```